# How to setup a WAN port in Cisco ISR 1111?

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios

The C1111-8p has 2 WAN ports and 8 switch ports. I am trying to set up the WAN port to an optical fiber modem, the ISP provided:

- IP address
- Mask
- Gateway
- DNS1 and DN2

I need to set up the port `GE 0/0/0` as WAN port. I couldn't find anything in the manual, it's the first time I setup a Cisco router.

```
interface gig 0/0/0
ip address NOT_LOCAL_IP 255.255.255.252
```

- **How to setup the gateway?**

More widely, the router will be connected to a single Cisco wifi AP through a single RJ45 Ethernet trunk port in one of the 8 LAN switch ports present in the router. The wifi AP needs to support 2 VLANs with 2 SSIDs. (1 VLAN = 1 SSID

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/1100/software/configuration/xe-16-8/cisco_1100_series_swcfg_xe_16_8_x/cisco_1100_series_swcfg_chapter_01000.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the correct path. The IP information is set on the interface, as you have already started. The default gateway should be the default route on the router. The DNS is set on the host.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 ip address YOUR_ISP_IP_ADD 255.255.255.252

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 YOUR_ISP_DEFAULT_GATEWAY
```

Now the router should be able to access the internet. You will have to setup a few other things for hosts to access the internet, like private IP subnet, VLAN, maybe NAT and DHCP etc.

You can test the connection via the router CLI:

`ping 1.1.1.1 source gi0/0/0`

Comment: I definitely have to add 2 LAN subnets, 2 VLANs, a NAT (if I want both VLANs access the Internet) and DHCP if I want my computers connected through wifi to have an IP address. Thanks!

Comment: I will have 2 VLANs with two different subnets in the router, will `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 ISPGW` be a problem? `0.0.0.0` includes the internal local subnets.`

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP if both subnets need internet, then yes, the default route will allow that for both.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to provide DNS to hosts connected? I used `ip name-server DNS1 DNS2`, I can ping a domain name from the router but not from the local network.

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP do you mean DNS for the router itself? Then yes, you need to use `ip name-server DNS1 DNS2`. For your hosts, you need to add the DNS servers to your DHCP scope, example: `ip dhcp pool YOUR_DHCP_SCOPE_NAME` then `dns-server DNS1 DNS2`

Comment: I tried but the hosts can't find the domain.

Comment: The DNS setting is on automatic in the hosts.

Comment: Without knowing your DHCP configuration, do your host get the IP address from the router?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92859/discussion-between-alexis-fr-jp-and-user56700).